# Is it possible to use the value of a variable when pattern matching instead of binding to it?

Tags: enums, pattern-matching, rust

Consider the following

```
enum FooBar {
    Bar,
    Foo,
}

struct Whatever {
    f_type: FooBar,
}

let what = Whatever { f_type: FooBar::Bar };
```

I know this works:

```
let answer: bool = match what {
    Whatever { f_type: FooBar::Bar } => true,
    _ => false, 
};
println!("{:?}", answer); // true
```

Is there a way to get this to work such that `bar_match` is used to compare the value instead of being bound to the current value?

```
let bar_match = FooBar::Bar;
let answer: bool = match what {
    Whatever { f_type: bar_match } => true,
    _ => false,
};
println!("{:?}", answer); // true
```

I'm a Rust noob but I can't find an answer to this question anywhere online.

Comment: FYI, the `: bool` is superfluous; the type is inferred by the value of the `match` arms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [match guards](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html#guards).

If you let `FooBar` derive from `Copy` `Clone` and `PartialEq` you can build `match guards` for its values:

```
let bar_match = FooBar::Bar;
let answer: bool = match what {
  Whatever { f_type } if f_type == FooBar::Bar => true,
  _ => false,
};
```

[Full play.rust-lang.org example.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=957faaff0d85666481b296149e292606&version=stable&backtrace=0)